# VBA code that interacts with PDF's opened in Internet Explorer? (no sendkeys)

Tags: excel, vba, navbar

I have been trying to create code that will interact with PDF files opened in IE. More specifically, I would like to search and pull text that meets my criteria from the document. It seems like the only solution I have found on the boards is to use sendkeys. Anyone else have a more efficient solution? Is it even possible?

Comment: Maybe you could expand on "interacts" ?

Comment: My apologies Tim. I am looking to search through the page and pull any of the text that meets my criteria. (Example: The code searches for the word "document". If it finds "document", then it pulls that word back to a cell) I have edited the question to reflect this.

Comment: I know this isn't VBA but this may prove to be more flexible. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6704/how-can-i-grep-in-pdf-files

Comment: Look for something called selenium vba. It’s a tool that can help you interact with browsers directly.

Comment: Thank you both for your input. However, unless I am missing something, selenium is used more for HTML interactions.When I am viewing a PDF in IE, wouldn't I need a different approach? @RicardoDiaz

Comment: If you have Adobe Acrobat (not Reader) installed on the same computer, you can search pdfs from the browser cache folders, open in Acrobat object, do the text search, but not sure about pulling texts around the result.

Comment: @PatricK I am using your suggestion as a work around right now. However, that solution slows down my code considerably because it has to: Open the PDF url, save the file in a temp location, open it in acrobat, run my logic on the document, and then move on to the next url. It works like a champ, but probably increases the run time by 100%. Thank you all for the suggestions, if I can figure out how to speed it up, I'll share my solution here.

Comment: Perhaps you can open all the PDF urls in IE, then catalogue all the PDF files in IE's cache folder within a days date modification, then open and search for the text.